# refresh data with sqldataadapter.fill - not seeing new data

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I have a timer that runs in the background to keep data updated for a datagridview object. My timer is calling sqldatadapter.fill to fill a local scoped dataset.

If I go over to sql server and delete a row from my table my call to fill the dataset does not reflect this change from the database.

If I update the value of a non primary key field at the database and my timer runs the changes are picked up and shown in my datagridview.

How do I need to set up my sqldataadapter so that it will find when rows are added or deleted by some other backend process?

This is in form_load

```
If ds Is Nothing Then
        ds = New DataSet()
    End If
    Try
        sqldataadapter = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(SELECTQUERY, parentconnectionstring)
        sqldataadapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        sqlcommandbuilder = New SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(sqldataadapter)
        sqldataadapter.Fill(ds)
        mydata = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionHandler(ex)
    End Try

    If mydata.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        bindingsource.DataSource = mydata
        dgvSystemWeightConfig.DataSource = bindingsource
        UpdateLastUpdateTime()
    End If
```

And this is my refresh routine

```
 Public Sub refreshdata()
    disableupdatetimer()
    Try
        If dgvSystemWeightConfig.IsCurrentCellInEditMode Then
            Debug.WriteLine("tried to refresh system weight data but user had a cell in edit mode")
        Else
            Debug.WriteLine("system weight - refreshing data")

            sqldataadapter.Fill(ds, mydata.Table.TableName)
            dgvSystemWeightConfig.Focus()
            UpdateLastUpdateTime()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ExceptionHandler(ex)
    Finally
        enableUpdateTimer()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If you downvoted would you mind leaving a comment to let me know what you thought was lacking or incorrect? I always try to provide as much issue context and source code to help others understand what i'm going through and your comments will help me get better at this process.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume the SqlDataAdapter does not have the correct records. Apparently DataTable implements INotifyPropertyChanged but does not implement INotifyCollectionChanged. Bind to an ObservableCollection.

Debug and get a count on ds.
I bet the source is correct and the UI control is just not picking up the changes.

For the UI to pick up inserts and deletes you need to have a source that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged.

DataTable does a lot of stuff you need to replace.
Will need a class or struct to hold the rows and will need to define the columns.
AutoGenerateColumns only works with DataTable.

Comment: the visual studio dataset visualizer is showing the old data too. If I create a new dataset and fill that object instead then I get correct data. So it's something to do with my dataset that is hanging around in memory. I don't have classes for my objects so I can't use observablecollection.

Comment: Are you sure?   Put a ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count in the refreshdata and verify.  I makes no sense that an old ds would hang out in memory if you add or delete a row but the ds would not hang out in memory if a row changed.